# distractingly long full path in irb/console error outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This' a minor one but it keeps bugging me.

Can I omit the full path of the rails console (or irb) from error outputs like the following?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_g' for 8:Fixnum
from (irb):3
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

leads to linebreaks, takes up lots of space, more noise then it requires attention.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In IRB you can set the backtrace limit, i.e.: `irb --back-trace-limit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will not be a very straightforward thing to accomplish if you intend to only scrub the path from script/console and/or irb.  You can look at how Kernel decides what to print for stack traces, but in general, it is not advisable to try and monkey with this -- it can create a lot of unexpected behaviors.